# About the control of threejs

Tags: three.js

I am practicing threejs while watching the tutorial.
However, one problem occurred.
Mouse control code is not working. Only black screen.
I checked, but it's exactly the same code as the tutorial.
But mine doesn't work.
I am the latest version of Chrome and I got the latest file from OrbitControls.js from GitHub.
I think the only difference from the tutorial is the OrbitControls.js file.
What should I do?

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/110/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
    <script>

      window.addEventListener('load', init);

      function init() {
        const width = 960;
        const height = 540;

        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
          canvas: document.querySelector('#myCanvas')
        });
        renderer.setSize(width, height);

        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, width / height);

        camera.position.set(0, 0, 1000);

        const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera);

        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
          new THREE.BoxGeometry(300, 300, 300),
          new THREE.MeshNormalMaterial()
        );
        scene.add(mesh);

        tick();

        function tick() {
          renderer.render(scene, camera);
          requestAnimationFrame(tick);
        }
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="myCanvas"></canvas>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One common root cause for such importing issues is the usage of `three.js` components from different releases. You can easily verify this by importing your code like so:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.110/build/three.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.110/examples/js/controls/OrbitControls.js"></script>
```

Another possible problem is the way you create `OrbitControls`. In recent versions of `three.js`, the second parameter is mandatory. Meaning the code should look like so:

```
const controls = new THREE.OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
```

Comment: I checked the behavior with your code and it is perfect. I check the release version, download it and try again. Thank you.